# Is it possible to have different schema for different shards in same collection in solr?

Tags: solr

I have created a collection for clothing products and for each clothing store there is a shard created and routing is done based on clothig_store_id.

Now, the problem is from store to store there are many fields which aren't common.

I can solve this problem by either creating dynamic field or have all extra fields of all store in my schema file.

Is there any better way to solve it? or is it even possible to maintain different schema for shards?

Comment: Or you can create one collection for each store? CREATEALIAS allows you to create an alias pointing to multiple collections as well - but searching across collections with different schemas won't do much good for scoring.

Comment: I have a common field "text" and others across all shards. If I go with this strategy, will i be able to search on created ALIAS  across all collections?

Comment: That should work. Test it out in small scale. Otherwise, the option is to keep a normalized collection with all the data, and one collection for each store. Scoring might be more sensible in that case.